# Creating a DAX measure for previous month charges in Power Query Pivot Table

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, measure

I'm using Power Query to pull some billing information from a Sharepoint Folder. The fisrt image shows this table.

I then want to summarise this with a Pivot Table based on the billing period.

The second image shows my pivot table. I'm trying to create a measure 'Previous Month' that will give me the Total Charges for the previous month for each row - however I'm struggling. Please note - sometimes the different companies will be billed on different date periods - I still wish this to be based on the month the Bill Period End Date falls in.

[image]

[image]

This is the measure that I've created, but as you can see it only provides the 'Apr' value in the Grand Total.

```
=CALCULATE(
SUM(Billing[Total Charges excl. Vat]), 
FILTER(Billing,
Billing[Billing Period End Date (Month Index)] = MAX(Billing[Billing Period End Date (Month Index)])-1)
)
```

I've searched several forums but cannot find an answer.

| Invoice Date | Billing Period Start Date | Billing Period End Date | Company Name | Total Charges Excl VAT | Billing Period End Date (Year) | Billing Period End Date(Quarter) | Billing Period End Date (Month Index) | Billing Period End Date (Month) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company A | 10.35 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company A | 10.35 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company A | 10.35 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company A | 10.35 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 10.35 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 10.35 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 10.35 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 10.35 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company A | 27.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company A | 27.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company A | 27.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company A | 27.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 27.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 27.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 27.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 06/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/03/2023 | 31/03/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 3 | Mar |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company A | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company A | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company A | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company A | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company A | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 11.10 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 05/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 31/05/2023 | Company B | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 5 | May |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company B | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company B | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company B | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company B | 29.00 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company B | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company B | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company B | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company B | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |
| 04/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 | Company A | 9.71 | 2023 | Qtr2 | 4 | Apr |

Comment: Please paste your sample data as copiable text

Comment: How can I do that in a comment? 

I can no longer add a table to the original post?

Comment: Edit your original post

Comment: I've updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
=VAR p = CALCULATE(MAX(Billing[Billing Period End Date (Month Index)])-1)
VAR s = CALCULATE( SUM(Billing[Total Charges Excl VAT]),FILTER(ALL(Billing),Billing[Billing Period End Date (Month Index)] = p))
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE(Billing[Billing Period End Date (Month Index)]), s)
```

Comment: Thank you David. 

This is almost perfect. If I wanted it to work across multiple years how could I apply that filter - At the moment this would combine May 2023 and May 2022? 

Also, how could I have this compare January 2023 to December 2022?

Comment: Hi Gordon - you could add a KEEPFILTERS() on year to the filter list. The answers to these questions depend on the sample data you provided. I suggest you mark this as solved and ask a brand new question with all the required and new sample data along with explicit requirements.

Comment: Ideally, you should create a proper date table and a model so you can use simpler time intelligence functions like PREVIOUSMONTH()

Comment: Thanks David. I do have a date table, but I couldn't get it to work with PREVIOUSMONTH(). 

I'd created a relationship between the 'Billing Period End Date' and the CalendarDate in my Date Table.

Comment: I've managed to adjust it a little bit and have it working - thank you so much for your help @David Bacci.